# Little help putting together a delete statement in SqlLite using OrmLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, ormlite

I have trouble putting together a delete statement in my Android application (I am using OrmLite).

I have a table filled with records. Two of the fields are "dateCreated" (`type Date`) and "imageSize" (`type int`). In my code I have a method `free(int size)`. This method tells me that I have to delete oldest records from my table that sum "imageSize" `<=` size.

For instance .. i get parameter 1000. Each record has value lets say 100. That means i have to delete 10 of the oldest records.

Can some one please provide me with optimal raw SQL statement or even better an OrmLite code for this?

I would be most gratefull.

Comment: So if each image has a size of 100 and you say free(1000), then all images will match, right?  Where does the 10 come in?  Is that a constant?

Comment: Any feedback on my answer @no9?

Comment: sorry Gray i havent received a notification on this anwser. Yes it was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do this with a single SQL statement.  There is no way to say

> select records until their sum is less than X

You could doing multiple queries until you found the oldest records whose sum is less than X but it would take a number of separate SQL calls.

I'd recommend selecting the last X images with their sizes and then doing a delete of the right number of images using a `DELETE ... IN ...`.  Here's the pseudo code:

```
while (true) {
   SELECT id, imageSize FROM yourtable ORDER BY dateCreated DESC LIMIT 10;
   find the images from the bottom whose sum(imageSize) <= parameter
   delete the found images
   break if you exceed the parameter otherwise loop and get the next 10
}
```

Comment: this might do the trick, i have implemented something similar and it is consuming alot of resources, will use this solution instead

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE imageSize <= (SELECT SUM(ImageSize) FROM yourtable)
```

Use the same parameter for your function

Comment: you did not understand my question. I need to delete oldest records that their SUM (image size) is <= "size"

Comment: @no9 I have updated the query,hope this is the query you needed